# Regex to find a price within a string

Tags: java, regex

Hi a service I am using returns prices in the form 00003600 or 00013650

I would like to transform this to a string of the form 36.00 Euro or 136.50 Euro.
Can this be done using regex.

Thanks,

Comment: Don't use regex. This is a perfect case for a `BigDecimal`. Read as int, then modify `scale`.

Comment: Note that the leading zeros make the number interpreted as octal number. So, `010` is actually `8`.

Comment: `010` is considered octal only when part of source code

Comment: This is all you need: `System.out.println(new BigDecimal("00003600").scaleByPowerOfTen(-2));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case the other answers were not clear enough

```
String text = "00003600";
BigDecimal value = new BigDecimal(text).scaleByPowerOfTen(-2);
System.out.println(value);
```

prints

```
36.00
```

OR

```
String text = "00003600";
double value = Double.parseDouble(text) / 100;
System.out.printf("%.2f%n", value);
```

prints

```
36.00
```

Comment: *The right way* is to call `scaleByPowerOfTen(-2)` -- replaces both `setScale(2)` and `divide` -- and is of trivial complexity. That's what I actually had in mind in my comment. It just modifies the `scale` attribute with no recalculation at all.

Answer (score 4):

just parse the string and then divide by 100.  Or use BigDecimal and scale.

Comment: Looks like @MarkoTapolnik beat me to the BigDecimal answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Most correct way (IMHO):

```
String input = "00013650";
BigDecimal value = BigDecimal.valueOf(Long.parseLong(input), 2);
String output = value.toPlainString();
System.out.println(output);
```

Outputs:

```
136.5
```

Comment: Why would you pass it a long when BigDecimals are designed to accept string input?

Comment: Tha'ts just so I can pass the scale in the same method call :)

Comment: Id avoid doing this, using `new BigDecimal(input).setScale(2)` would be much better.

Comment: I'd say "much better" is a bit of a reach as it's essentially the same thing, but I see your point and I can kind of agree that it's a leaner way of doing it.

Comment: Id say not casting to a Long first is deffinately a much better way, unless you have other code to catch exceptions which parseLong may throw.

Comment: Of course I would be more cautious with exception handling in production code... In a code example however, skipping it improves readability